# Why does my python loop give a different array every run, and how to make it produce the same result everytime?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, while-loop

You can see the loop below, which gives a different plot everytime, and approximately 1 out of 20 runs is the result that I want, which is a triangular Fourier series. How to make it so that the outcome is the same everytime?

```
L=1
N=1000

#Array for x
x=np.linspace(-3*L,3*L,N+1)
#Array for sum
s=np.empty(N+1) 
#While loop for sum
i=1
while(i<N+1):
    s=(1/((2*i-1)**2))*(np.cos((2*i-1)*np.pi*x/L))+s
    i=i+1

print(s)
#f(x)
y=(L/2)-(4*L/((np.pi)**2))*s

#Settings for plot
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: please, add the needed import statements so that your code is self contained and can be replicable.  Also, adding the libraries you are using as tags can be nice. Not all Python code uses numpy or matplotlib.

Comment: btw, this may very well be the source of your problem: there are no random elements in the snippet above, but this way of using matplotlib creates a stateful object which can possibly keep some state from previous plots in subsequent cell runs.

Comment: im sorry im new to this, how would i do that?

Comment: *s* is initialized as 'empty' without changing the values that are present in the allocated memory block and then added to the computed values `s=(1/((2*i-1)**2))*(np.cos((2*i-1)*np.pi*x/L))+s`. This is not random, but undefined behaviour.

Comment: You probably meant `s=np.zeros(N+1)` instead.

Comment: how would I delete the allocated memory block before s is added to the computed values?

Comment: You are using `s` to calculate the next `s`.  What value should it start with? We are guessing you want to start with 0s, and iterate from there.  Anyways, `np.empty` is not what you want for this kind of iteration.  Details may vary, but often we don't need to 'allocate' memory before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
s=np.empty(N+1)
```

produces an array filled with undefined(arbitrary) value. You should be using a new array filled with zero instead:

```
s=np.zeros(N+1)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy, technically the term is 'undefined', not 'random' (as produced by one of the pseudo random number generators.

Comment: @KellyBundy no because it's not really (or even pseudo) random

Comment: @KellyBundy Previously I ran into some problem that need to allocate large array efficiently. The conclusion (back then) was that there is no significant performance difference. Though this should be different with different machines

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out the `np.empty` is giving you problems.  Your loop with an initial print of `s`:

```
In [26]: L=1
    ...: N=10
    ...: 
    ...: #Array for x
    ...: x=np.linspace(-3*L,3*L,N+1)
    ...: #Array for sum
    ...: s=np.empty(N+1)
    ...: print(s)
    ...: i=1
    ...: while(i<N+1):
    ...:     s=(1/((2*i-1)**2))*(np.cos((2*i-1)*np.pi*x/L))+s
    ...:     i=i+1
    ...: 
[-3.  -2.4 -1.8 -1.2 -0.6  0.   0.6  1.2  1.8  2.4  3. ]
In [27]: s
Out[27]: 
array([-4.20872131, -2.15330145, -1.06005191, -1.93994809, -0.84669855,
        1.20872131,  0.35330145,  0.46005191,  2.53994809,  2.64669855,
        1.79127869])
```

Same thing but with `np.zeros`:

```
In [28]: L=1
    ...: N=10
    ...: 
    ...: #Array for x
    ...: x=np.linspace(-3*L,3*L,N+1)
    ...: #Array for sum
    ...: s=np.zeros(N+1)
    ...: print(s)
    ...: i=1
    ...: while(i<N+1):
    ...:     s=(1/((2*i-1)**2))*(np.cos((2*i-1)*np.pi*x/L))+s
    ...:     i=i+1
    ...: 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
In [29]: s
Out[29]: 
array([-1.20872131,  0.24669855,  0.73994809, -0.73994809, -0.24669855,
        1.20872131, -0.24669855, -0.73994809,  0.73994809,  0.24669855,
       -1.20872131])
```

But you don't need to iterate.  Instead create `i` range of values, and construct a 2d result (broadcasting the (11,1) `x` against the (10,) `i`:

```
In [30]: i = np.arange(1,N+1)
In [31]: S = (1/((2*i-1)**2))*(np.cos((2*i-1)*np.pi*x[:,None]/L))
In [32]: S.shape
Out[32]: (11, 10)
In [33]: s.shape
Out[33]: (11,)
```

Then sum across the `i` dimension:

```
In [34]: S.sum(axis=1)
Out[34]: 
array([-1.20872131,  0.24669855,  0.73994809, -0.73994809, -0.24669855,
        1.20872131, -0.24669855, -0.73994809,  0.73994809,  0.24669855,
       -1.20872131])
```